# music app to monitor a USB drive

Tags: macos, itunes, music

I have a USB stick of thousands of songs which I want to be able to play on my work laptop (macos).

Ideally I want to set up the "Music app" (renamed iTunes) so that it will monitor the USB stick and automatically detect if new music has been added to it (on my personal windows PC foorbar2000 does this for me). Is there a way to do it in mac music?

What I have tried so far. In the "Music App" I have:

- Disabled option to "copy when adding to library"
- Disabled option to "keep music organised"

Then I use "Add folder to library" and it kind of works. But it seems to stop, after a while and does not add all the music. It seems to run in alphabetical folder (Artist) order. First time stopped during "A". If I do "Add folder to library" again it adds more music, I have repeated a few times and got to "D".

- Is there some reason the "Add folder to library" is not working properly? Does it have limits? Or does it give up if in background for too long or if laptop goes to sleep?

But even if add does work, its will not automatically monitor for changes like foobar does right?

I also tried changing the setting of where the music app keeps media to the USB stick, but that didn't work either, nothing shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option to "watch" a folder. You manually add all music in a folder regularly, Music will not duplicate what it already had imported.

The function should work properly, it will just take very long for large libraries as the music app is fairly slow when importing.